# using $_GET in PHP with https

Tags: php, ssl, https, query-string, get-request

I am trying to pass a variable to another page on a https:// connection without much success. Below is the query

```
https://mydomain.prefix/secure/myfile.php?claim_id=12345678
```

I then try and retrieve it using:

```
$claim_id=trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['claim_id']));
```

This unfortunately does not work and I was wondering if it was the ssl that is stopping this. If so, how can I pass this variable to my page from an a href link ?

Comment: ssl shouldn't have anything to do with your issue and $_GET should work...

Comment: `<?php echo $_GET["claim_id"]; ?>` should return `12345678`

Comment: Actually this method does work - for some reason by trying to stick it into $claim_id as above it doesn't... Thanks for your help but it has got me puzzled :)

Comment: Does the claim id have to be a string or can it be an int?

Comment: Break up your combined statement into multiple steps like:
$claim_id = $_GET['claim_id']; echo $claim_id; $claim_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $claim_id); echo $claim_id; etc to show exactly where it breaks down.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, an echo $_GET['var_name']; works on http but not on https, it returns an empty string. Did you be able to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to resume a concrete answer to this question:

**If you're having a problem like this look somewhere else, not in your HTTPS setup or PHP GET request and parameters.**

I have a problem like this, everything worked on HTTP and when I migrate the system to HTTPS not. I was not receiving the GET variable that I was expecting. After several hours of trying to find some problem related with the HTTPS setup and PHP config and code, the problems turns to be that I was not receiving the GET variable because a JS library, included in the HTML header, was not being included due to new restrictions in FF23 ( https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/ ). I change the JS include to HTTPS and everything works again.

The solution to this particular question(from Sideshow) turns to be a database problem.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

> This unfortunately does not work

....is not a meaningful description of the outcome. There's nothing intrinsically wrong with the code.

Try replacing

```
$claim_id=trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['claim_id']));
```

with

```
if (is_resource($dbc)) {
  $claim_id=trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['claim_id']));
  print "I got " . htmlentities($claim_id) . "<br />";
} else {
  print "I have no database handle! <br />";
}
print "ERR=" . mysql_error() . "<br />";
```

and show us what's actually happening.

Comment: This just outputs the text within statement with no errors - obviously a database connection problem - Thanks

Comment: If it were a database connection problem then an error should be reported.